# How can I change this?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-id, mac-appstore, apple-silicon

[image: fake popup message that i got on my macbook lockscreen]

fake popup message that i got on my macbook lockscreen

Comment: That’s not a fake pop up.  Your Mac is managed with MDM software.

Comment: How can i change this ?

Comment: When and from whom did you buy this Mac?

Comment: 1 August 2022 , and this message started to popup from January 15 (after i done software update) i buyed it from a reseller

Comment: If you have the receipt, try contacting Apple to see if it can be bypassed. The reseller procured this from a questionable source so you might have to go through them for resolution

Comment: You've been sold a stolen laptop. Get your money back, and then report the seller to the police.